# How can I reduce the time needed to run my code and what is the cause of the slow speed?

Tags: python

The code works well on small datasets as illustrated in the example code, but the data set I have to process are two lists picker and order each with a length of 1592798 and 288 and 528510 unique values respectively.
For the sake of the example I have replaced these with two short lists, but the concept is the same. I am wondering if the long time required to run the code is due to the sheer amount of data, or if the code is inefficient at processing the data and can be improved.

The purpose of the code is to group all pickers associated with a unique order into a list(hold) within a list(pairs). The order the elements occur in the pair list must be determined, by the first entry in each element on the list, for instance `[1, 'a']` must come before `[2, 'b', 'k']`, because 1 is a smaller number than 2. Regarding for instance `'b'`, `'k'` in `[2, 'b', 'k']`, the order of these is determined by which of these occurs first in the list picker. `'b'` comes before `'k'` because `'b'` has a lower index.
The current code looks like this

```
order  = [ 1,   2,   3,   4,   1,   5,   3,   6,   7,   1,   8,   9,   4,   4,   2,   8,   4,   4,   2 ]
picker = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'b', 'h', 'j', 'j', 'k']
pairs = []

order_picker = list(zip(order, picker))

for x in set(order):
    hold = []
    hold.append(x)
    for i in range(len(order_picker)):
        if x == list(order_picker[i])[0]:
            if list(order_picker[i])[1] not in hold:
                hold.append(list(order_picker[i])[1])
    pairs.append(hold)

print(pairs)
```

The output from the print(pairs)

```
>>> print(pairs)
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b', 'k'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd', 'j', 'k'], [5, 'e'], [6, 'f'], [7, 'g'], [8, 'h'], [9, 'i']]
```

The output must be on this format for me to later write it to excel.

I suspect that the long time required to run the code occurs due to checking the entire list of length 1592798 each time a new value must be identified, but I have been unable to create a faster solution. How can I reduce the time required to run the code.

Comment: Does order matter? Could `[2, 'b', 'k']` come before `[1, 'a']`? Could `[2, 'b', 'k']` instead be `[2, 'k', 'b']`?

Comment: The order matters, I added an explanation based on your question. I hope it clarifies it.

Comment: And why those orders? Are they supposed to be the order in which the values appear in the input, or are they supposed to be sorted, or something else? Your own solution uses the order of a set, which is arbitrary.

Comment: The order the elements occur in the pair list must be determined, by the first entry in each element on the list, for instance  `[1, 'a']` must come before `[2, 'b', 'k']`, because 1 is a smaller number than 2. I assumed set would assure the correct order from smallest to largest. Regarding for instance `'b', 'k'` in `[2, 'b', 'k']`, the order of these is determined by which of these occurs first in the list picker. 'b' comes before 'k' because 'b' has a lower index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast solution with the [desired orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898386/how-can-i-reduce-the-time-needed-to-run-my-code-and-what-is-the-cause-of-the-slo/75899567#comment133874735_75898386):

```py
def pairs(order, picker):
    d = {o: {} for o in sorted(set(order))}
    for o, p in zip(order, picker):
        d[o][p] = None
    return [[o, *p] for o, p in d.items()]

order  = [ 1,   2,   3,   4,   1,   5,   3,   6,   7,   1,   8,   9,   4,   4,   2,   8,   4,   4,   2 ]
picker = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'b', 'h', 'j', 'j', 'k']

print(pairs(order, picker))
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZFBbsIwEEXFNqeYXWIUKtFSGpB6BS5gZQF40hhU25qYBSBOwoYNHKqnweNQq6rw4i3-_P9ta843t_etNZfLdeebUfUzOCtswC01dYUlhVSC0-stkphnEI6CTzjaORxP0FgCC9pAZ8mjKjr0fUSIU_RGQ8iz56Dd077YKW0tXR2aF9ZglAn9jgxIGfLDMPpbpV60x--uEHWWxUoISQnjMuReGW-MCSNq70mbMj7SoGLMknmSCqp_GtRZ_2i-KF_mJeQrxpqhGFHDpDWMrzRoGZqxYWxTQZu0xyB8yZE2vni2AdHv6LGq35XdAQ)):

```
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b', 'k'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd', 'j', 'k'], [5, 'e'], [6, 'f'], [7, 'g'], [8, 'h'], [9, 'i']]
```

Comment: Neat trick with the nested dict. Will remember that for another time - and thx for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can speed up your code by only looping over the elements in `picker` and `order` once

In the example I made, I am zipping the two lists, and using a defaultdict consisting of sets to add each element. Finally, the dictionary is converted to your desired output format

```py
from collections import defaultdict

order = [1,  2,  3,  4,  1,  5,  3,  6,  7,  1,  8,  9,  4,  4,  2,  8,  4,  4, 2]
picker = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'b', 'h', 'j', 'j', 'k']

pairs = defaultdict(set)
for o, p in zip(order, picker):
    pairs[o].add(p)
pairs = [[k, *v] for k, v in pairs.items()]

print(pairs)
```

Comment: Why a mocked defaultdict instead of a real one?

Comment: it could just as well be a real one, just wanted to avoid imports for simplicity - maybe it adds more confusion -- edit: changed to defaultdict, probably easier to understand and also a bit faster than setdefault

Comment: Ok, maybe. On the other hand a real defaultdict may be faster as it avoids creation and destruction of a lot of unused sets.

Comment: you are still iterating 3 times : 1x zip and 2x for

Comment: @gui3 zip is a generator so that doesn't cost us anything. it yields the values as requested. and yes the final conversion loops as well, but it's not a nested loop as in OP's example, so it shouldn't cost a lot of performance

Answer (score 0):

It takes long because you iterate multiple times on the same data : `zip`, `for` and `for`

Try to optimize by iterating less,

something like this produces the same output with only 1 `for` loop

```py
order  = [ 1,   2,   3,   4,   1,   5,   3,   6,   7,   1,   8,   9,   4,   4,   2,   8,   4,   4,   2 ]
picker = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'b', 'h', 'j', 'j', 'k']


order_indexes = {} # stores indexes of orders
pairs = []

for i in range(0, len(order)):
    order_item = order[i]
    picker_item = picker[i]

    if (order_item not in order_indexes):
        order_indexes[order_item] = len(pairs)
        # the index it will be inserted in
        pairs.append([order_item]) 
        # insertion of new order
  
    if (picker_item not in pairs[order_indexes[order_item]]): 
        pairs[order_indexes[order_item]].append(picker_item)
        # add picker if not already present
        
print(pairs)
```

Comment: Might still be slow, as you're searching in lists.

Comment: I tested your solution vs my solution on a sample size of 1 million. on my computer my solution performed a bit faster (8.22ms vs 25.2ms)

Comment: @oskros That's sounds suspiciously fast. Are you sure you did that correctly?

Comment: @KellyBundy good catch, i had mistakenly typed 100k and not 1mill in my sample generation - at 1mill its 89.5ms vs 1.66s

Comment: the speed of different solution strongly depends on the shape of the data... If i understand well, the OP's order is limited (288). This is to be taken into account.

Comment: But i must say my code was just an attempt at doing it in only 1 loop. I admit it's far from optimized, because of `ifs` and indeed of looking up the lists

Comment: @oskros Ok, that's more reasonable. How about using the numbers they gave us? I.e., like [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3z2TmFuQXlSgUJeal5OdyceWk5qWXZCjYKhiaWhqZW1pwleZlFpamxucXpaQWFQPFgQrTUzWMLCw0YVIFmcnZELmczOISjdzEAo3ikiIdqEpTIwtTQwNNTU0uLrAZECOAduklZ-RnJqcWa6DYoKOQbQtxgyYXxGCcGqD2IumA-AnqNZgXAQ).